# Convert an Int type to a tuple identifier in scala?

Tags: scala, indexing, tuples

Is it possible to convert an `Int` to a **tuple identifier** (in scala)? So for a working example suppose I had this:

```
   val testTuple = ("Hector", "Jonas", "Javi")
   val id = 2
   println(testTuple._id) // does not work as it tries 'num' as a name parameter
```

I can see that tuple elements can be accessed by the order in which they appear - much like an index (except the first value is 1 rather than 0), e.g. `testTuple._1 // is Hector` would work as described [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-tuple-examples-syntax#accessing-tuple-elements) among other places.

**So how can this be done?** Many thanks

Comment: Using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you can convert the tuple to an array/vector and access it by index

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`testTuple.productElement(id - 1)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Product.html). But note that this returns `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

NO, You can not do this. `_n` is a member of `tuple<n>` and it automatically equals to the size of tuple. According to the notes:

> For each TupleN type, where 1 <= N <= 22, Scala defines a number of
>   element-access methods.

Ex:

```
val data = (4,3,2)
val sum = data._1 + data._2 + data._3
```

For more information, you can see [Scala Tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm).

Thanks.